# Android Studio - Rendering Problems for XML files using support libraries

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I get rendering problems for XML files that uses support libraries, while I don't have the same for normal XML files. These are the errors I get for separate XML files

**Error**

```
*The following classes cannot be found:
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar*
```

**a) Android Studio version: 1.2.1.1**

**b) Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.piserve.geejo.mskv4"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'
   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

**c) Layout XML file** (one of them)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/color_primary"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
   app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolbarTheme"
>
```

**d) SDK Manager Screenshot**

[image: 1]

Here's what I tried:

***a) Changing the theme in the editor window to Material and Holo themes***

***b) Switching between Android v21 and v22***

***c) Tried different emulators from Nexus 4-10***

Comment: Anyone can address this problem and offer me a solution? I guess this started ever since I updated to the latest version.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170841

Comment: Did you update the support library repository in SDK Manager?

Comment: @Gabrielli: It is the latest version

Comment: @Pavel: I saw that before, changed gradle version to 1.1.3 and the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. None of the solutions worked for me so I had to revert back to Android Studio 1.1.0: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/1-1-0

Comment: Reverting back to 1.1 was the only thing that managed to solve this for me, even when running the 1.3 preview.